# A very complex problem in reduction notion

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, np-complete, computation-theory, reduction

I have studied many about reduction but I have a bad problem in it:
I take this from CLRS :

" ... by “reducing” solving problem A to solving problem B, we use the “easiness” of B to prove the “easiness” of A."

And I take this from "Computational Complexity by Christos H. Papadimitriou  " :

" ... problem A is at least as hard as problem B if B reduces to A."

I got confused with these two notion:
when we use easiness , we say that problem X reduces to problem Y and if we have polynomial time algorithm for Y and reduction process is done in polynomial time then problem X is solvable in polynomial time and X is easier than Y or at least is not harder than Y.

But when we use hardness , we say problem X reduces to problem Y and Y is easier than X or at least is not harder than X.

I really got confused, Please help me.
Special thanks.

Comment: You probably need to ask this on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Preet: cstheory is a site for researchers. This question would be closed as off-topic in a heart beat over there.

Comment: Please don't. From http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq, "we welcome research-level questions in theoretical computer science (TCS) ... It does not include questions at the level of difficulty of typical undergraduate". You could try http://math.stackexchange.com/faq if you don't get a decent answer here, that is for lower-level math questions, including computer science.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might have missed that the first quote says "reduce A to B", and the second quote says "reduce B to A".

If X reduces to Y, meaning that Y can be used to solve X, then X is no harder than Y. That's because polynomial-complexity reduction is considered "free", so by reducing X to Y we've found a way to solve X using whatever solutions there are to Y.

So, in the first quote, if A reduces to B and B is easy, that means A is easy (strictly speaking, it's no harder).

The second quote uses the logical contrapositive: if B reduces to A and B is hard, then A must be hard (strictly speaking, it's no easier). Proof: If A was easy, then B would be easy (as above but A and B are reversed). B is not easy, therefore A is not easy.

Your statement, "we say problem X reduces to problem Y and Y is easier than X or at least is not harder than X" is false. It is possible for X to reduce to Y (that is, we can use Y to solve X), even though Y in fact *is* harder than X. So we could reduce addition (X) to a special case of some NP-hard problem (Y), by defining a scheme to construct in polynomial time an instance of the NP-hard problem whose solution is the sum of our two input numbers. It doesn't mean addition is NP-hard, just that we've made things unnecessarily difficult for ourselves. It's unwise to *use* that reduction in order to perform addition, since there are better ways to do addition. Well, better assuming P!=NP, that is.

Comment: Why when we say A reduces to B then we can conclude B is at least as hard as B ?

Comment: We use reduction to reduce hard problem to easy problem and then for what when we say A reduces to B then we can conclude B is at least as hard as B ?

Answer (score 2):

Think of reduction as reduction of the proof for the problem being in a certain class rather than reducing the problem itself. The relation is more related to logic than to complexity.

Answer (score 1):

The theory is simply this.

You have an algorithm to solve problem A that you know can be solved in polynominal time.

If it is possible to convert problem B into a notation that can be solved by problem A and then convert the result back into the notation for problem B in polynominal time, then to solve problem B will also be in polynominal time - as the total time is just the addition of two polynominals - hence no harder.